# Why is my collection returning [object Object] instead of the string of text I inserted?

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my Meteor app, I'm having an issue with my collection only returning `[object Object]` instead of the string of text I inserted.

In console, typing `MyCollection.insert({sometext: "hello"});` I insert "hello" into sometext. Now as you can see in the code below, the template infoOutput with the `{{output}}` returns what I have inserted. Now it works, except it displays `[object Object]` within the div I've placed `{{output}}` into in the template.

I want to be able to display the string "hello" or whatever string of text I insert instead. I also want to be able to update and write over that string of text so instead of there being a list of text strings returned, I want only one string and that string to be changed each time I insert a new text string the way Session.set would change a string.

I'd appreciate the help. Thanks

In my client.js file I have:

```
MyCollection = new Meteor.Collection('MyCollection');

if(Meteor.isClient) {
Template.infooutput.output = function() { 
return MyCollection.findOne(); }
}
```

In my server.js file I have:

```
MyCollection = new Meteor.Collection('MyCollection');
if (Meteor.isServer) {
}
```

I have a template:

```
<template name="infoOutput">
<div id="outputText">
{{output}} 
</div>
</template>
```

and then in my main page

```
<body>
{{>infoOutput}}
</body>
```

Comment: don't you mean to get `{{output.sometext}}` ?

Comment: ah, you're right. Completely forgot.

Comment: How do I replace it though? should I use update? or use a Session.set

Comment: I'm not up on Meteor and how it binds data - first step would be give the user an input of course `<input type="text" value="{{output.sometext}}"/>` - . Opening another question on that might be better - or make very bold the part where you ask about updating.

Comment: @Brandon do you have solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<template name="infoOutput">
<div id="outputText">
{{output.sometext}} 
</div>
</template>
```